# For every pandas dataframe column with 'phone', remove non-numerals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a python dataframe (df) created from a csv. I want to take every column name that contains 'PHONE' (or 'phone' or 'Phone') and change all their rows to be in the format of 5555555555. So:

(555) 555-5555 would be 5555555555,

555-555-5555 would be 5555555555,

and so on.

I tried the following, but got a syntax error. Hopefully I was at least kinda-sorta close:

```
phone_format = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('PHONE')]
for col in phone_format:
    df['col'] = df.['col'].map(lambda x: x.replace('.', '').replace(' ', '').replace('-', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` to select the columns with "phone" (in a case-insensitive way using the `(?i)phone` regex) and `apply` with `str.replace` to remove the non-digits, finally `update` the DataFrame **in place**.

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='(?i)phone').apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True)))
```

Example:

```
# before
           pHoNe  other Phone  other col
0  (555) 55 5555  555-555-555    (55-55)

# after
       pHoNe  other Phone  other col
0  555555555    555555555    (55-55)
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pHoNe': ['(555) 55 5555'], 'other Phone': ['555-555-555'], 'other col': ['(55-55)']})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
phone_format = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('PHONE')]
for col in phone_format:    
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r"\D+", "", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

From using your code as a starting point for a minimal working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['(555) 555-5555', '555-555-5555']], columns=['phone', 'Phone'])
phone_format = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat='PHONE', case=False)]
for col in phone_format:
    df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: x.replace('.', '').replace(' ', '').replace('-', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))
df
```